# Recommend folder(s) in Xcode Build Phase?

Tags: ios, build

Can anyone recommend what folder(s) should be used in Xcode Build Phases for an iOS deployment to copy one (1) user data file and one (1) system data file? The deployment target is iOS  v.5.1.  I read in the Apple Developer Library that the user data file should be located in Application_Home/Documents and the system data file should be located in Application_Home/Library?  Seems strange to me that these are not in the Destination drop down or are they called something else like Resources?  I don't want the user data file overwritten during an AppStore update.  Thanks...

1. Copy files (1 item)
   Destination: Absolute Path
   Sub path: Application_Home/Documents
   Copy only when installing
2. Copy files (1 item)
   Destination: Absolute Path
   Sub path: Application_Home/Library
   Copy only when installing

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you want to confirm that after an app update, you want the files not to be overwritten. For this refer [this](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/82693-fix-for-app-deleting-users-files-on-update.html)

> Files Saved During Application Updates
>   When a user downloads an application
>   update, iTunes installs the update in
>   a new application directory. It then
>   moves the user’s data files from the
>   old installation over to the new
>   application directory before deleting
>   the old installation. Files in the
>   following directories are guaranteed
>   to be preserved during the update
>   process:
>
> ```
> <Application_Home>/Documents
> <Application_Home>/Library
> ```
>
> Although files in other user directories may also be moved over,
>   you should not rely on them being
>   present after an update.

For Documents Directory Path

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *docsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
```

For Library Directory Path

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *docsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
```

For more Paths refer [Apple Application Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Constants/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSSearchPathDirectory)

Comment: Am I responsible for creating these folders or will they be created as part of the Apple deployment??

Comment: folders would be created as part of the Apple deployment.. you need to store your files in these folders